# Weird error with eqnarray

Tags: equations, errors

The following piece of code

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\expval[\mathcal{N}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{N}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} + 0.280 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^2} ~, \\
\expval[\mathcal{L}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{2 \rho_1^{3/2}} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{L}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\pi \rho_1^2} + 0.147 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^3} ~.
\end{eqnarray*}
```

gives the following error.

```
! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.34 \var(\mathcal{N}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1}
                                                + 0.280 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\...
```

I have defined `\expval` and `\var` in the document preamble as follows.

```
\newcommand{\expval}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\var}{\mathrm{Var}}
```

Just wondering what the issue could be.

Comment: The use of `eqnarray` is outdated and should be replaced by something more advanced; offered in the form of `align` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Moreover, `eqnarray` only allows a singular alignment, while you're attempting to align more than one equation (further motivating the use of `align`).

Comment: @Werner, ahh. I had ever only used `eqnarray` once, so didn't know it had that limitation! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should rather use `align*` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\expval}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\expval[\mathcal{N}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{N}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} + 0.280 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^2} ~, \\
\expval[\mathcal{L}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{2 \rho_1^{3/2}} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{L}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\pi \rho_1^2} + 0.147 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^3} ~.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

See more discussion on this topic from [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure about the error in `eqnarray` however, first I suggest you read:

[Eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/7049)

and realize that `eqnarray` is really bad for you! :)

Then you should notice that whenever you need to define a function (or operator) it is best to do so by `\DeclareMathOperator`. That will yield better spacing for you.

Also better let `TeX` do the spacing. Just my opinion. :)

So in effect you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expval}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \expval[\mathcal{N}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1}        , &
  \var(\mathcal{N})    &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1}+0.280 \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^2}, 
  \\ % Next line
  \expval[\mathcal{L}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{2 \rho_1^{3/2}} , &
  \var(\mathcal{L})    &= \frac{\rho_0}{\pi \rho_1^2} + 0.147 \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^3}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `eqnarray` you use 3 `&` this is the problem.

If you want align at 3 places use `alignat` tag, see below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\expval}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\var}{\mathrm{Var}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
\expval[\mathcal{N}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{N}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_1} + 0.280 \, \frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^2} ~, \\
\expval[\mathcal{L}] &= \frac{\rho_0}{2 \rho_1^{3/2}} ~, &
\var(\mathcal{L}) &= \frac{\rho_0}{\pi \rho_1^2} + 0.147 \,
\frac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_1^3} ~.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```